# Simple counter button android

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to make a simple counting button, like in picture I have attached below

[image]

The simplest way I can imagine is to define two buttons and one textview. 
Is there any better solution for this aim?

Comment: no there is no such widget available which has such a ui you need to right custom

Comment: Just interesting: What was the reason for downvote this question?
If the question is pointless, or it is created uncorrectly, please point me on my mistake, and I won't repeat it next time. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is `no such widget available` which has such a ui you need to right custom 
or do the way you're doing

Answer (score 1):

> The simplest way I can imagine is to define two buttons and one
>   textview.

If you want to create a "simple counting button" then This is the most obvious way to do it...

Comment: that what he is doing he asked for alternative

Comment: What alternative should there be? Like you said, there is no such "counting widget" available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, two `ImageButtons` and a `TextView` (along with the counting logic) would be how you should do it.

Comment: you could use regular `Button` instead of `ImageButton`

Comment: @FoamyGuy : Yes sir, absolutely. Only that the question had some images on the buttons and I find using ImageButton really easy and simply when I need to attach any image to a Button.